# Trying to aggregate postgres table values with recurrent values

Tags: postgresql, subquery, aggregate

I have a table with two columns: first an id column (let's call it ID) and second a value column (let's cal it VALUE). The VALUE column can have two values: 'One' and 'Two'. Most IDs appear once in the table with as value 'One' OR 'two'. However, the are some IDs that appear twice in the column: one time with value 'One' and the second time with value 'Two'. I am now trying to write a query that results in a table with two columns in which all IDs appear only once. The first column should contain the ID, the second should countain the values 'One', 'Two' or 'One and Two' in case the ID had two both values in the original table. My query untill now:

```
WITH (
    SELECT id, 'One & Two' as value 
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
 ) AS  both_values, (
    SELECT id, value 
        FROM table_name
      WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM both_values)
     ) AS other_values
 SELECT * FROM other_values
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM both_values;
```

This seams not to work and I can't manage to write a simple query to get this result. Can somebody help me please?

EDIT: adding ::varchar after 'One & Two' did it. However, it doesn't seem an effinctien query to me. Any ides to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT value, ' & ' ORDER BY value),id    
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY id
```

Not that difficult...